# How to implement a single function to return data after AsyncTask or synchronously if previously cached?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, caching, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement caching in an Android app. I’m have added a static global array as

```
public static State[][] stateList = new State[Country.values().length][];
```

Here country is always fixed so I’ve made an enum but the states tend to change every now and then so I pull the data from the server (which has a nice backend where I can edit / add / remove states).

I have a simple country dropdown selection with a listview below which changes automatically once the selection is made. My current implementation makes a pure network request like this...

```
new FetchStatesTask(this, country, mProgressBar, view).execute();
```

It shows the progress bar during the network fetch and then onPostExecute stops it and then makes a callback `onStatesFetched(State[] states)` which has code to repopulate the listview properly.

But I want to implement caching so the idea is to store the fetched data in `stateList` array. My original idea was to do something like this..

```
if(stateList[country] == null)
  // Do network request FetchStatesTask and then call onStatesFetched with result
else
  // Directly call doStatesFetched passing stateList[country]
```

But I am looking for an alternative like..

```
public static State[] getStateList[]
{
if(stateList[country] == null)
  // Do network request FetchStatesTask and then return State[] after async operation
else
  // Return stateList[country]
}
```

This way I can remove the callback listener and use a single function that does the entire process of fetching the states and returning and acts both synchronous in case of already stateList being cached in the array or async if not cached before. I’m not sure how I would go about implementing said logic so help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original idea is fine because as you said it is used in `dropdown in android app` so there can't be many of such actions concurrently. Keep it simple. But it's better to declare `State[][] stateList` as `volatile`. Because according to Java Memory Model `volatile` gives "Visibility guarantees".

Here is brief explanation ["What does volatile do?"](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)

If you still want to use `State[] getStateList()` than do it in a Double Checked Locking style

```
private static volatile String[][] stateList;
...

public State[] getStateList() {
    if (stateList[country] == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (stateList[country] == null) {
                // Do network request FetchStatesTask and then return State[] after async operation
            }
        }
    }
    return stateList[country];
}
```

But in this case I can't understand why do you need "*return State[] after **async** operation*" because such function signature means that after thread enters `getStateList()` in case when `stateList[country] == null` this thread would wait before `async operation` is done and only after that `return State[]`. So calling `State[] getStateList()` always would act synchronous (more accurately, blocking). If method returns non-void value and waits for blocking operations to be done it can't be non-blocking or as you said `async if not cached before`.

So either you use your original idea or use FetchStatesTask (holding `stateList` cache) every time and do network request only if it is empty.

Comment: Great inputs. Thank you very much